# Impose mixed boundary conditions for a PDE in the Fourier domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I have the following PDE to solve with an initial dirac condition.
$$
\frac{\partial p(t,y)}{\partial t} = y \frac{\partial ^2 p}{\partial ^2 y} + (2-\alpha + y) \frac{\partial p}{\partial y} +  p
$$

The simplest way I could think of was to Fourier transform it relative to the second variable y, and solve the first order PDE that comes using the method of characteristics. 
It looks pretty good except for one thing: I don't know how to express the following mixed boundary condition in the Fourier domain...

**$$
s(t, y) = -\frac{\partial ( y p(t,y)}{\partial y} + (\alpha - y) p(t,y)
$$ 
must be equal to zero at $y_{min}$ and $y_{max}$ for any $t$.**

Is there a way?

Comment: Why don't you post the full details of your problem, because it doesn't particularly make sense as it is. Also edit to include all of your working so far.

Comment: The question is just about how to transform my PDE and its boundary conditions in the Fourier domain and the problem lies in the boundary conditions only. The initial condition is ok: $p(0,y) = \delta _x(y)$ so in the Fourier domain with the space frequency $k$ it gives $P(0,k) = e^{-ixk}$ with $P$ the Fourier transform of $(t,y) \mapsto p(t,y)$ relative to its second variable. In the Fourier domain my equation reads: $\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + (i k^2 + k) \frac{\partial P}{\partial k} = - \alpha i k P$ . Now: how to impose $\forall t, s(t, y_{min}) = s(t, y_{max}) = 0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I doubt that your Fourier transform is 100% accurate - since the right-hand side has terms with first order derivatives, there must be imaginary units somewhere.

Second, your condition $p(t,y_0)=0$  can be written as an application of a delta-distribution:
$$\langle \delta_{y_0}, p(t,y)\rangle = 0.$$ Take a Fourier transform to obtain (up to some constants from the normalisation of Fourier transform)
$$\langle \exp(i\xi y_0), \hat p(t,\xi)\rangle = 0 = \int_\Bbb R \hat p(t,\xi)\exp(i\xi y_0)d\xi.$$

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig your second remark a little bit, but I don't get the first one: there are imaginary units in $\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + (i k^2 + k) \frac{\partial P}{\partial k} = - \alpha i k P$

Comment: @ClementRoussel I meant that your second equation (with $s(t,y)$) looks a bit weird - if it meant to represent the Fourier transform of the initial equation.

Comment: ok I see the confusion, in fact this second equation defines my problematic boundary condition but not in the Fourier domain: $-\frac{\partial ( y_{min} p(t,y_{min})}{\partial y} + (\alpha - y_{min}) p(t,y_{min}) = 0$ and $-\frac{\partial ( y_{max} p(t,y_{max})}{\partial y} + (\alpha - y_{max}) p(t,y_{max}) = 0$